# Calc question about inequality and electric circuit theory

Tags: calculus, inequality

In electric circuit theory, the combined resistance $R$ of two resistors $R_1 > 0$ and
$R_2 > 0$ connected in parallel obeys

$$\frac{1}{R} = \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}$$

Show that $$R < \sqrt{\frac{R_1 R_2}{2}}$$. This proves that $R$ cannot be large if the individual
resistances $R_1$ and $R_2$ are small.

Can anyone show me how to solve this questions?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $a+b \geq 2 \sqrt{ab}$ for $a,b, >0$. As the resistances are given to be greater than 0, this inequality holds.

$\frac{1}{R}=\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}=\frac{R_2+R_1}{R_1R_2} \geq \frac{2\sqrt{R_1R_2}}{R_1R_2}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{R_1R_2}}> \sqrt{\frac{2}{R_1R_2}}$

Taking the reciprocal of both sides yields the inequality desired: $R<\sqrt{\frac{R_1R_2}{2}}$